# Visual Studio Windows Phone 10. Исключение - BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, sqlite3, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Во время запуска универсальной программы Windows10 на телефоне, происходит исключение BadImageFormatException. На MSDN написано, что выдается при недопустимом образе файла библиотеки динамической компоновки (DLL) или выполняемой программы. Исключение происходит в строках:

```
path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "MyDB.db");
conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
```

Я правильно понимаю, что на телефоне, нужно по другому указать путь к локальным файлам? Если да, то какой путь нужно указывать (path)?

Answer (score 4):

Подключаться правильно нужно так:

```
await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("MyDB.db");
Connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("MyDB.db");
```

[Тут](http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2013/01/29/SQLite-in-Windows-Phone-8.aspx) есть гайд

Comment: Представленный гайд для Windows Phone 8. В расширении Sql.net-pcl нету и в помине SQLiteAsyncConnection. Такое решение не подходит.

Comment: Проверил в 13-й студии для WP8, данный метод присутствует. Сейчас обновиться 15-я студия, и проверю еще там, но я очень сомневаюсь в том, что я не обнаружу там этот метод.

Comment: я использую универсальный проект, который идет для всех платформ с виндовс 10 (поэтому не ожидал исключения на телефоне, на пк работает).

Comment: Я в курсе. В универсальном приложении в 13-й студии все есть.

Comment: до этого я считал, что универсальные приложения появились только с появлением 10 винды этим летом в 15 студии.

Comment: использовал информацию для подключения SQLite с [этой](http://blog.chrisbriggsy.com/Using-SQLITE-in-Windows-10-IoT-Core-Insider-Preview/) страницы.

Comment: вам нужно доставить sqlite-net-pcl и все

Comment: не понял смысл формулировки - "доставить". Ссылка в проекте есть. Все работает, если запускать на ПК. На телефоне получается вышеуказанное исключение.

Comment: Вы сказали, что вы не можете найти метод SQLiteAsyncConnection, я вам ответил где его взять.

Comment: подключить можно только using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
using SQLite.Net.Interop;
using SQLite.Net.Platform